# Unexpected end of file; Misplace of brackets?

Tags: php

I'm getting an error with my code.

`Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpcart5\products.php on line 41.`

Is it an error of brackets or because of the while loop?
Can someone please help?

```
<?php  session_start();?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Shoping Cart </title>
    <!-- This page is for displaying the products -->
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div align="center">
    <h3 style="background-color:#FF0">Products</h3>
    <a style="color:#FFFF00; text-decoration:none" href="cart.php?action=none"><span style="margin-left:500px;">
    <img src="online/images/cart.png">Cart (<? echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?>
    )</span></a>
    </br>
    <table border="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" cellpadding="0px" width="600px">
    <?php
    //Fetching the product details from database
    include("common/db.php");
    $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <!-- Displaying the shopping cart product -->
        <td>
        <img src="<?=$row['picture']?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <b><?=$row['name']?>
        </b><br/>
        <?=$row['description']?>
        <br/>
        Price:<big style="color:#455E5B">
        $<?=$row['price']?>
        </big><br/><br/>
        <a href="cart.php?id=<?=$row['serial']?>&action=add "><img src="images/add.png"/></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <hr size="1"/>
        </td>
    <? }?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: which one is line 41 ?

Comment: Are [short tags](https://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled?

Comment: 1. SO isn't an online debugger! 2. Do you have short open tags on? 3. Use an IDE 4. It also could be in: `common/db.php`

Comment: Yes short tags are enabled....

Comment: Let's pretend they're not. Change `<? } ?>` to `<?php } ?>`

Comment: The error could be in included `common/db.php`. Could you post it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using PHP short tags in your script (`<? /* PHP statement */ ?>`). If any `short_open_tag` setting in your php.ini file is set to `Off`, then those PHP tags would cause issues.

The correct way to solve this in PHP 5.4 and later versions? Use `<?php /* statement */ ?>` instead:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <!-- This page is for displaying the products -->
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div align="center">
    <h3 style="background-color:#FF0">Products</h3>
    <a style="color:#FFFF00; text-decoration:none" href="cart.php?action=none"><span style="margin-left:500px;">
    <img src="online/images/cart.png">Cart (<?= count($_SESSION['cart']) ?>)</span></a>
    </br>

    <table border="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" cellpadding="0px" width="600px">
        <?php
        //Fetching the product details from database
        include("common/db.php");
        $result = mysql_query("select * from products");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- Displaying the shopping cart product -->
            <td>
                <img src="<?= $row['picture'] ?>"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b><?= $row['name'] ?>
                </b><br/>
                <?= $row['description'] ?>
                <br/>
                Price:<span style="font-size:larger;color:#455E5B">
                    $<?= $row['price'] ?>
                </span><br/><br/>
                <a href="cart.php?id=<?= $row['serial'] ?>&action=add "><img src="images/add.png"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr size="1"/>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If, for some reason, you are unable to use PHP 5.4+ (which is bad; PHP 5.3 is no longer supported), then the easiest thing to do would be to *also* replace instances of `<?= $value ?>` with `<?php echo $value; ?>`

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <!-- This page is for displaying the products -->
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div align="center">
    <h3 style="background-color:#FF0">Products</h3>
    <a style="color:#FFFF00; text-decoration:none" href="cart.php?action=none"><span style="margin-left:500px;">
        <img src="online/images/cart.png">Cart (<?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']);?>)</span></a>
    </br>

    <table border="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" cellpadding="0px" width="600px">
        <?php
        //Fetching the product details from database
        include("common/db.php");
        $result = mysql_query("select * from products");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- Displaying the shopping cart product -->
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo $row['picture'];?>"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b><?php echo $row['name'];?>
                </b><br/>
                <?php echo $row['description'];?>
                <br/>
                Price:<span style="font-size:larger;color:#455E5B">
                        $<?php echo $row['price'];?>
                    </span><br/><br/>
                <a href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $row['serial'];?>&action=add "><img src="images/add.png"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr size="1"/>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```